# itunes connect metadata rejected video third party, how to resolve?

Tags: app-store-connect

I uploaded my app to itunes connect and I waited a few days.. and then the app that I uploaded was denied one time. I send them one video explaining the app, but anyway they rejected the app.

This is the first message:

We began the review of your app but are still not able to continue because we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use when launched on the physical device and **integrating with third party product**. Please showcase all app features and functionality within the video content provided. The simulation video provided will not suffice.

This is the second message:

The simulation video provided will not suffice. We need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use when launched on the physical device, and integrating with the third party product. Please showcase all app features and functionality within the video content provided.

What do I need to do? Use a screen capture software and film my app in use in the iPhone? Upload to youtube and share the link in the review notes of the app? A simple demonstration? or a expanded demonstration?